# Moving a Plone site to Radiant CMS

Tags: plone, radiant

I've got a large Plone site that I'm moving to Radiant (I love Plone, but it got unusably slow as the site grew). I need a little help with some of the equivalences.

1. How do I do user permissions, signup, login, etc? I'd love to be able to have content that's:

   - Viewable by anyone (status "Published")
   - Viewable by authenticated users (status "Semi-published")
   - Viewable by "staff" (status "Restricted")
2. The Plone content has a few attributes that I don't find in Radiant, specifically "Creators" and "Contributors". I could conflate them down to a list of authors if I need to, but Radiant seems to want "author" to be used for the login that instantiated the content. How would I handle extending the page model to handle them?
3. How do I do site search? I'd love to be able to search by either free text or by assigned keywords (which come from a particular taxonomy, as it turns out).
4. The biggest issue is transferring content. I can ftp most of the content out of the Plone site. For HTML documents that'll mean that I've got files that look like:

```
    id: a-banking-system-we-can-trust
    title: A Banking System We Can Trust
    excludeFromNav: False
    subject: Alternate economy
    description: Turn all financial firms into mutual funds.
    contributors: Forbes
    creators: Laurence J. Kotlikoff
      Edward Leamer
    effectiveDate: None
    expirationDate: None
    language:
    rights:
    creation_date: 2009/05/05 21:01:58.795 GMT-4
    modification_date: 2009/05/05 21:06:39.695 GMT-4
    relatedItems:
    allowDiscussion: None
    Content-Type: text/html


    <h1>A Banking System We Can Trust</h1>
```

> How might I take a whole (Linux) directory tree full of files like that (as well as some images and PDFs) and turn them into Radiant content, complete with the correct metadata (that's the first few lines of the files, when you use FTP to get them).

Comment: Plone site getting slow as it grows is usually fixable; we have customers running Plone sites with 150k content items without problems. <advert>We can help by doing a performance review of the Plone site</advert>.

Comment: Since I do a lot of work on Plone 2.5 I can definitively relate. However, to me, upgrading to a newer Plone version seems like a much less daunting task than migrating to a new CMS. Take a look at the performance improvements documented here http://blog.hannosch.eu/2010/01/plone-4-how-much-faster-is-it.html

Answer (score 1):

I've used a product called [ilrt.contentmigrator](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ilrt.contentmigrator) recently to migrate a Plone 2.x site to Plone 4.x, pretty simple. You really should check out Plone 4, the speed difference is significant!